# On django heroku deployment with postgres database getting error: DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value

Tags: django, database, postgresql, heroku, deployment

Hi I am new to Heroku and I am trying to deploy my django app on the site. The issue I am running into is in the title. It seems to have an issue connecting to my postgres database. In my local environment, the database works perfectly fine this issue only seems to come up with the heroku deployment. I have added the DATABASE_URL already as a config var on Heroku. The app deploys but just says Internal Server Error, Here is the error logs heroku is giving me:

```
 raise ImproperlyConfigured(
2020-12-14T23:41:58.543920+00:00 app[web.1]: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value.
2020-12-14T23:41:58.544131+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.148.121.8 - - [14/Dec/2020:23:41:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "-" "-"
2020-12-14T23:41:58.545021+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=premtablelive.herokuapp.com request_id=aa3e9556-0490-4690-8b0b-d414e69a0305 fwd="24.190.19.51" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=500 bytes=244 protocol=https
```

I'm not sure what is causing this issue I am not spelling the name value for my database wrong in my code as it works in my local environment.

here is my settings:

```
from pathlib import Path
import django_heroku 
import os


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxx'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['premtablelive.herokuapp.com','127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'table',
    'django_filters'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'PremTable.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': '',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'PremTable.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'premtable',
        'USER': 'xxxxx',
        'PASSWORD':'xxxxxx',
        'HOST': 'database-1.casge6lscm2l.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT':'5432',
    }
}
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age = 600)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)



# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/



STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')



django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Here is my Procfile

```
web: gunicorn PremTable.wsgi --log-file -
```

Here is my requirements

```
asgiref==3.3.1
boto3==1.16.35
botocore==1.19.35
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.1.3
django-filter==2.4.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-storages==1.10.1
freeze==3.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
jmespath==0.10.0
Pillow==8.0.1
psycopg2==2.8.6
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.4
s3transfer==0.3.3
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
unicorn==1.0.2
urllib3==1.26.2
whitenoise==5.2.0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I haven't really been able to find a solution to this problem anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead, this way, you will automatically configure your database URL to the one provided by heroku

```
from dj_database_url import parse as dburl 
from decouple import config

default_dburl = "sqlite:///" + os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3")


DATABASES = {"default": config("DATABASE_URL", default=default_dburl, cast=dburl)}
```

Comment: heroku provides "config vars" which can be read using decouple, and heroku automatically provides DATABASE_URL

Comment: Heroku's config vars are just environment variables. You don't need any special library to read them; `os.environ` or `os.getenv()` works just fine. Thanks for clarifying what `config` is, though.